# Laravel Voyager - upload image on front-end with custom form

Tags: laravel-5, file-upload, voyager

I'm working with the voyager (Laravel). I have a model with an image field, this model was created in the backoffice and I already have CRUD for it. I wanted to create a form in the frontend so there could be submited of unlogged users. But I do not know how to upload to follow the same rules that the voyager uses in the backoffice (automatically generated CRUD)

Any help? Thank u

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use the voyager views and controllers
First you can create a controller that extends VoyagerBaseController
https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/overriding-files

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController as BaseVoyagerBaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use TCG\Voyager\Database\Schema\SchemaManager;
use TCG\Voyager\Events\BreadDataAdded;
use TCG\Voyager\Events\BreadDataDeleted;
use TCG\Voyager\Events\BreadDataUpdated;
use TCG\Voyager\Events\BreadImagesDeleted;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;
use TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\Traits\BreadRelationshipParser;
use App\Image;
use App\Document;
use App\Property;
use App\Demand;

class CustomVoyagerController extends BaseVoyagerBaseController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // GET THE SLUG, ex. 'posts', 'pages', etc.
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        // GET THE DataType based on the slug
        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        // Check permission
        $this->authorize('browse', app($dataType->model_name));

        $getter = $dataType->server_side ? 'paginate' : 'get';

        $search = (object) ['value' => $request->get('s'), 'key' => $request->get('key'), 'filter' => $request->get('filter')];
        $searchable = $dataType->server_side ? array_keys(SchemaManager::describeTable(app($dataType->model_name)->getTable())->toArray()) : '';
        $orderBy = $request->get('order_by');
        $sortOrder = $request->get('sort_order', null);

        // Next Get or Paginate the actual content from the MODEL that corresponds to the slug DataType
        if (strlen($dataType->model_name) != 0) {
            $relationships = $this->getRelationships($dataType);

            $model = app($dataType->model_name);
            $query = $model::select('*')->with($relationships);

            // If a column has a relationship associated with it, we do not want to show that field
            $this->removeRelationshipField($dataType, 'browse');

            if ($search->value && $search->key && $search->filter) {
                $search_filter = ($search->filter == 'equals') ? '=' : 'LIKE';
                $search_value = ($search->filter == 'equals') ? $search->value : '%'.$search->value.'%';
                $query->where($search->key, $search_filter, $search_value);
            }

            if ($orderBy && in_array($orderBy, $dataType->fields())) {
                $querySortOrder = (!empty($sortOrder)) ? $sortOrder : 'DESC';
                $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([
                    $query->orderBy($orderBy, $querySortOrder),
                    $getter,
                ]);
            } elseif ($model->timestamps) {
                $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$query->latest($model::CREATED_AT), $getter]);
            } else {
                $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$query->orderBy($model->getKeyName(), 'DESC'), $getter]);
            }

            // Replace relationships' keys for labels and create READ links if a slug is provided.
            $dataTypeContent = $this->resolveRelations($dataTypeContent, $dataType);
        } else {
            // If Model doesn't exist, get data from table name
            $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([DB::table($dataType->name), $getter]);
            $model = false;
        }

        // Check if BREAD is Translatable
        if (($isModelTranslatable = is_bread_translatable($model))) {
            $dataTypeContent->load('translations');
        }

        // Check if server side pagination is enabled
        $isServerSide = isset($dataType->server_side) && $dataType->server_side;

        $view = '**YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_HERE**';

        if (view()->exists("voyager::$slug.browse")) {
            $view = "voyager::$slug.browse";
        }

        return Voyager::view($view, compact(
            'dataType',
            'dataTypeContent',
            'isModelTranslatable',
            'search',
            'orderBy',
            'sortOrder',
            'searchable',
            'isServerSide'
        ));
    }
}
```

https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/overriding-files#overriding-bread-views

And create your custom view inheited from voyager edit-add blade that is here
\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\bread

copy edit-add.blade.php, 
edit with your preferences, 
change in the controller $view = '**YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW_HERE**'; with the real route to the resource.

Now you are using in the front the controller and the view from laravel, remember load all you need from the laravel layout